# Deleting record from ps_image_lang

Tags: prestashop

What inconsistency can be produced when deleting a record from ps_image_lang table if this record does not exist in ps_image or ps_image_shop in prestashop database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any. This record should not exist if ID image doesn't exist in `ps_image` nor `ps_image_shop`.